# Django localhost returns ok but curl localhost returns the 404 error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, gunicorn

The localhost of a Django app runs normal on an AWS server like the following:

```
(env) manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Django version 2.2, using settings 'xyz.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

The curl -i localhost is returning the 404 error.
(env) $ curl -i localhost

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What does this mean? Does it mean the Django app was installed ok but the Nginx is not working properly? What do I check them out? The tech stack is Django/Python/gunicon/Nginx on Ubuntu 18.

Solved.
The nginx.conf has the same two server names. One was removed and it works.

Comment: Did you open the ports for outside access ?

Comment: Can you share the nginx conf?

Comment: I fixed it. The nginx.conf has the same server names, threw a warning but not an error. Anyway, thanks.